# Disable node modeuls folder caching on heroku to reduce slug size?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to disable node modules on heroku to decrease the slug size for better bootup time, any idea where to use the following command ?

heroku config:set NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false

[Src](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#custom-caching)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Heroku CLI. And you will run that command on the terminal.

Useful links =>

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-cli

---

Also, there is a UI for managing configs.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#using-the-heroku-dashboard